# Zoom to a vector feature in a vector layer

Tags: openlayers-2, vector, features, zoom

I am using OpenLayers+GeoServer and I have a vector layer in a map with some features 
I would like to make a zoom and show the map centered in one of these features that I can get by ID.
How can I do this operation?

Comment: I tried to get the bounds of the feature and then pass it to zoomToExtent() method of the layer. The problem is that bounds properties and getBounds() method of the feature return null

Comment: What kind of features are you dealing with? points or lines or polygons?

Comment: they are MultiLineString